C# & EF Core : when add-migration, a exception is thrown " unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''
This is my first time asking for help on Stack Overflow. If there are any rules that I didn't follow, just point them out, and I'll take note of them in the next question.
An exception was thrown when I run
add-migration v1.0.0

This is the code of my service:
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureDbContextPool(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration,IEnumerable<string>? includeDbNames = null,IEnumerable<string>? ignoreDbNames = null)
{
    var models = configuration.GetSection("DatabaseConnections").Get<List<DbConnectionModel>>();

    if (models == null || models.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("未配置数据库连接");
    }

    models = models
        .Where(includeDbNames != null, model => includeDbNames!.Contains(model.Name))
        .Where(ignoreDbNames != null, model => !ignoreDbNames!.Contains(model.Name))
        .ToList();

    models.ForEach(model =>
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<SystemDbContext>(options =>
        {
            switch (model.Provider)
            {
                case DbProviders.NpgSql:  
                    options.UseNpgsql(model.ConnectionString,optionBuiler => optionBuiler.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssembly)); 
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
    return services;
}

This is the code of my dbContext:
public class SystemDbContext:DbContext
{
    public SystemDbContext(DbContextOptions<SystemDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        DynamicLoadDbSet(modelBuilder);
        // 获取所有继承自 IEntityBase 的实体类型
        var entityBaseType = typeof(IEntityBase);
        var entityTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && entityBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));

        // 为每个实体类型应用 ConfigurableEntityBase 配置
        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            var method = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods()
                .First(m => m.Name == "Entity" && m.IsGenericMethod)
                .MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

            var entityBuilder = method.Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
            // entityType 继承了TDbcontetxtlocator，所以获取泛型参数
            var dbContextLocatorType = entityType?.BaseType?.GenericTypeArguments.Where(a=>a.GetInterface(nameof(IDbContextLocator))!=null).FirstOrDefault();

            if (entityType == null || dbContextLocatorType == null)
                continue;

            var configType = typeof(ConfigurableEntityBase<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, dbContextLocatorType);
            var configInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(configType);

            var configureMethod = configType.GetMethod("Configure");
            configureMethod?.Invoke(configInstance, new[] { entityBuilder });
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void DynamicLoadDbSet(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        foreach (Type type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type != typeof(EntityBase<SystemDbContextLocator>) && typeof(EntityBase<SystemDbContextLocator>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                var method = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Entity").FirstOrDefault();

                if (method != null)
                {
                    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });
                    method.Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I guess the problem may cast on
var configType = typeof(ConfigurableEntityBase<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, dbContextLocatorType);

But what should I correct it

Can you please provide the exception?

PM> add-migration v1.0.0
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

sure,  that's the whole process.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Please take a look at the countless questions on this exception, for example this one. And then the next, and the next...

Thanks for your help,it's a good idea to make a simplest demo .
Here is  the github repository :"https://github.com/CN-Hang/DemoApi.git".
(Project use .net 8.0 )
It has been marked with "#error" where the exception thrown,you can build and easily find it .
I already know the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. Do you have any good suggestions? Thanks.

I got it! I found code errors through debugging, very outrageous low-level errors,
My filtering of the types that need to be configured is invalid.
I will continue my development, sorry to take up your time.
